# Group by with printed weighted statistics in python / pandas

Tags: python, pandas, lambda, pandas-groupby

I have a table as a DataFrame like

| Fruit | Color | Weight | Tree |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Apple | Red | 0.1 | Tree1 |
| Apple | Green | 0.1 | Tree1 |
| Apple | Green | 0.9 | Tree2 |
| Apple | Yellow | 0.1 | Tree1 |
| Pear | Green | 1.0 | Tree2 |

I need an aggregation like:

| Tree | Fruits | Colors |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Tree1 | Apple - 100% | Red-33%, Yellow -33%, Green -33% |
| Tree2 | Apple - 50% , Pear - 50% | Green - 100% |

Now I do for each feature:

```
    dftotal=df.groupby(['Tree'])["Weight"].agg(['sum']).reset_index()
    dfFruit=dfFruit.groupby(['Tree']['Fruit'])['Weight'].sum().reset_index()
    dfFrwithTotal=pd.merge(dftotal,dfFruit)
    dfFrwithTotal['Weight']=100*dfFrwithTotal['Weight']/dfFrwithTotal["sum"]
    dfFrwithTotal['joined'] = dfFrwithTotal.apply(lambda x: str(x.Fruit)+' - '+ str(x.Weight) +'%', axis=1)
    dfsummaryFr=dfFrwithTotal.groupby(['Tree']).agg({ "joined": lambda x: ','.join(x)}).reset_index()
```

This looks highly ugly

And I do it for each feature and then merge on Tree

Is there a nice lambda expression for that?

Comment: Well that's a bad example. You can't just count freqs. The formula   = W per Attribute per Tree /sum(W) per Tree. Sum W is not 1.

Comment: For `Tree2` you have `Apple - 50% , Pear - 50%` in `Fruits` column. Does this result accounting the weights `0.9` and `1.0`?

Comment: That's a mistake in the output. You are right. You should take weights in the account

Answer (score 3):

Input data:

```
>>> df
   Fruit   Color  Weight   Tree
0  Apple     Red     0.1  Tree1
1  Apple   Green     0.1  Tree1
2  Apple   Green     0.9  Tree2
3  Apple  Yellow     0.1  Tree1
4   Pear   Green     1.0  Tree2
```

The formatting function to display results:

```
val2str = lambda s: ', '.join(map(lambda v: f"{v[0]}-{round(v[1], 1)}%", s.items()))
```

Convert the dataframe to a series indexed by Tree, Fruit & Color:

```
sr = df.set_index(["Tree", "Fruit", "Color"]).sum(axis="columns").sort_index()
```

```
>>> sr
Tree   Fruit  Color
Tree1  Apple  Green     0.1
              Red       0.1
              Yellow    0.1
Tree2  Apple  Green     0.9
       Pear   Green     1.0
dtype: float64
```

Generate series of display string:

```
fruits = \
    sr.sum(level=["Tree", "Fruit"]).mul(100).div(sr.sum(level="Tree")) \
      .unstack(level="Fruit").apply(lambda x: val2str(x[x.notna()]), axis="columns")

colors = \
    sr.sum(level=[0, "Color"]).mul(100).div(sr.sum(level="Tree")) \
      .unstack(level="Color").apply(lambda x: val2str(x[x.notna()]), axis="columns")
```

Merge `fruits` and `colors` together:

```
>>> pd.concat({"Fruits": fruits, "Colors": colors}, axis="columns")
                        Fruits                                Colors
Tree
Tree1             Apple-100.0%  Green-33.3%, Red-33.3%, Yellow-33.3%
Tree2  Apple-47.4%, Pear-52.6%                          Green-100.0%
```

Answer (score 2):

```
g_tree = df.groupby("Tree", sort=False)
weights = g_tree["Weight"].agg(list=lambda x: [pd.Series(list(x))], sum="sum")


def get_string(x):
    return " ".join(
        "{}-{:.2f}%".format(*v)
        for v in zip(
            x.values,
            weights.at[x.name, "list"][0].groupby(x.values).sum()
            / weights.at[x.name, "sum"]
            * 100,
        )
    )


out = pd.concat(
    [g_tree["Fruit"].apply(get_string), g_tree["Color"].apply(get_string)],
    axis=1,
).add_suffix("s")

print(out)
```

Prints:

```
                         Fruits                                 Colors
Tree                                                                  
Tree1             Apple-100.00%  Red-33.33% Green-33.33% Yellow-33.33%
Tree2  Apple-47.37% Pear-52.63%                          Green-100.00%
```

Comment: Wow! +1. Change the column names (plural form) ;-)